# ASP.NET Configuration Website For Membership - database setup (aspnet_ tables) - having problems pointing to the right database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership

I'm setting up membership in my ASP.NET MVC4 app, so I open the solution and then from there, I open up the ASP.NET Configuration website option under the "Project" menu.  This opens up the ASP.NET Configuration tool to create/modify/delete users.  What I'm finding is when I create a user, it creates the user in a local database when I specifically set in the web.config to point to a DIFFERENT database hosted with my web hosting company. I put `<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />` to remove the connection defined in machine.config.

Here's the connection string in the web.config for my app:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=cp.speedwell.arvixe.com; Initial Catalog=*********; User ID=********; Password=********;" />
```

Here's my database structure that's with my web hosting company.  As you can see, I have all of the aspnet_ tables already created:

[image]

When I click on "Providers" in the ASP.NET Configuration tab, here's my list of providers:

[image]

DefaultMembershipProvider is pointed to "DefaultConnection" which is the connection string to the database hosted with my web hosting company.  When I click "Test", it immediately comes back saying:

[image]

Finally, when I click on Security, here's the message I get (keep in mind I removed LocalSqlServer from my connection strings):

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here are my Membership, Profile, RoleManager, and SessionState sections of my web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1440156.aspx/1) thread and see if it helps.

Comment: No, that didn't work... I mean, removing LocalSqlServer and renaming my connection string to LocalSqlServer allowed the database connection to happen successfully, but now I have no idea where my users are being stored, because it's not on the database I want.

Comment: Could you post membership, roleManager, profile and sessionState(if there) tags of web.config?

Comment: I updated my question with your requested information at the end, @Win

Comment: When I click on the Security tab, I get the message "The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 251)"

Comment: But I already removed LocalSqlServer by way of <remove> in the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my Users/Roles/Etc were actually being inserted into the correct database all along- they were being inserted into the Users table, not the aspnet_Users table, as I would expect.  This is because my app was configured to use the asp.net universal providers.

Since I'm using MYWSAT,  and it requires the old aspnet tables, I removed the universal providers and it now has moved past that problem.  The reason I was getting that message saying that it couldn't establish a connection to the database was exactly because of this.

Answer (score 2):

In your Web.config,
Just replace this,

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

with this,

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remove **LocalSqlServer** instead you need to remove **DefaultConnection**.

```
<remove name="DefaultConnection" />
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" .../>
```

Beside, if you use new [ASP.Net Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx), you do not need to use `aspnet_regsql.exe` to generate tables which is deprecated.

`ASP.Net Universal Providers` uses Entity Framework.

If your database is new (no existing data), my suggestion will be to delete that database and use ASP.Net Universal Providers to create tables (no need to use aspnet_regsql.exe).

Place `<clear/>` inside tag before `add`.

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: You're talking about the tables Users, Roles, Applications, etc., right?  As opposed to the aspnet_ tables?

Comment: Yes. aspnet_XXX are deprecated.

Comment: Tables created by New ASP.Net Universal Providers do not have aspnet_ prefix.

Comment: You do not need sessionState since it is `InProc` which is default.

Comment: Why would I need to remove DefaultConnection?  DefaultConnection isn't defined anywhere (not even the machine.config) other than my local web.config.

Comment: It is just a safety net. You don't have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web.config pointing to that connection string for membership via connectionStringName like so:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="NameOfConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
```

Or could you be having build configuration issues? Have you verified that the uploaded config file is pointing to the right place?

Also try adding a clear before your declaration of membership:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
<providers>
 <clear />    
<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" ...
```

Comment: By "uploaded config file", what do you mean?  I'm running this locally at the moment, pointed to a non-local database in my web.config.

Comment: Here's what my provider looks like: <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

Comment: I see. And do you have build configurations/config transforms in place?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help.. it just cleared out settings inherited from machine.config.

Comment: Damn. This is a tough one. Sorry I've not been able to help thus far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27596/discussion-between-mike-marks-and-mobys-stunt-double)